# Remove data to the left and right of local minima

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpmisc

I have a lot of measurements where I get data that looks something like this:

```
# Generate example data
x <- 1:100
y <- 100*(1-exp(-0.3*x))
x2 <- 101:200
y2 <- rev(y)
df <- data.frame("x" = c(x, x2),
                 "y" = c(y, y2))
df$x <- df$x + 50
rm(x, x2, y, y2)
x <- 1:50
y <- 25.91818
x2 <- 251:300
y2 <- 25.91818
df2 <- data.frame("x" = c(x, x2),
                  "y" = c(y, y2))
rm(x, x2, y, y2)
df <- rbind(df, df2)
rm(df2)
```

If I plot this I can see that there are left-most and right-most local minima.

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point(data = data.frame("x" = c(50, 250), "y" = c(25.91818, 25.91818)),
             mapping = aes(x, y), colour = "red")+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 101))
p + annotate("text", label = "minimum 1", x = 50, y = 20) +
  annotate("text", label = "minimum 2", x = 250, y = 20)
```

[image]

What I would like to do is trim those data that are to the left of `minimum 1` and right of `minimum 2`. It's not super straightforward as there may also be local minima between those two points, because the real data doesn't look this ideal. I would also need to apply this process to many many samples, but I think this may be trivial because I could use e.g. `dplyr` and `group_by()`.

I had some luck plotting the local minima using the `ggpmisc` package, but I'm not sure how I can use that to actually subset my data. Just for clarity I included the code to do so below, and with the real data it looks a little better:

```
library(ggpmisc)
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y))+
    geom_line()+
    ggpmisc::stat_peaks(col="red", span=3)
p2
```

[image]

I hope this is clear and I'm happy to clarify any questions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I do not have completly clear what you are attempting. Are you trying to remove a baseline and extract the peaks? From the perspective of how to implement the code there are a few options that I can think of, but what will work best depends on the characteristics of your data. 1) Is the baseline always horizontal? 2) Is the spacing of obserbations along x homogeneous? (constant step?). 3) Do you need to draw plots, or did you use 'ggpmisc'  to describe/analyze the problem? I should be able to help if you answer these questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this using the following steps:

1. Sort your data according to its x co-ordinates
2. On your sorted data, find the `diff` of the y co-ordinates, which will be 0 (or close to 0) for the flat sections at either end (as well as any flat sections in between)
3. Starting from the left, find the first point where the `diff` is not zero (or at least is above a minimal threshold). Store this index as a variable called `left`
4. Starting from the right, find the first point where the `diff` is not zero (or at least is above a minimal threshold). Store this index as a variable called `right`
5. Subset your data frame so it only contains the data between rows `left:right`

So, in your example we would have:

```r
# Define a minimal threshold above which we are not at the minimum line
minimal_change <- 1e-6

df    <- df[order(df$x),]                                           # Step 1
left  <- which(diff(df$y) > minimal_change)[1]                      # Step 2
right <- nrow(df) - which(diff(rev(df$y)) > minimal_change)[1] + 1  # Step 3
df    <- df[left:right, ]                                           # Step 4
```

Now we can plot the result:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_point(data = data.frame("x" = c(50, 250), "y" = c(25.91818, 25.91818)),
             mapping = aes(x, y), colour = "red") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 101)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 300))
```

[image]